# How to navigate when button, check box response

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

My code igniter web page has side bar check boxes and news articles on main panel updated from database. when i select check box i want to pass check box `ID` to `controller` and return only relevant news articles according to check box value. How to do it? What is the mechanism using here?
example web site same as i [expected](http://www.carwale.com/used/cars-in-newdelhi/#city=10&pc=10&pn=1)

```
 <?php 
    foreach ($data as $add) {
        echo "<div>";
        echo '<p class="target">' .$add->news_data.  '</p>';
        echo "</div>";
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To Do that ...You have to make an ajax call "onclick" of checkbox group and then on ajax call you have to fire query with the IDs which have been passed

So,set AJAX function

```
$("#sidebar input[type='checkbox']").click(function(e){

           var values = [];    
           $( "input[name='post_type']:checked" ).each(function(){
           values.push($(this).val());
           });
          var Type = values.join(", ");

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "filterpost.php",
                data: "typID="+Type ,
                cache: false,
                success: function(){ 
                    alert("success");//just to check only 
                }
            });
     });
```

Step 2:Now create filterpost.php file

Now get the post value at the other side
$id = $_POST['typID'];
and from here fire the appropriate query using "IN" keyword

Step 3:
and pass that data to the view after that.

I can't give you the whole example directly...just follow this steps
I hope you will get solution

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][name="change"]').change(function() {
 if(this.checked) {
     // some ajax request
     } 
});
```

Similarly with plain JavaScript:

```
// checkbox is a reference to the element
checkbox.onchange = function() {
 if(this.checked) {
     // some ajax request
     }
};
```

And your function function return an JSON as your example